# What is correct image to spin up a VM in openstack using VBOX as host and centos 6.5 as allinone "guest"

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, rdo

I am running VirtualBox on my Mac Book pro.  I spun up a Centos 6.5 image within virtualbox and installed Openstack RDO (packstack allinone) without any issues.

I'm able to spin up the CIRROS default image without any issues (can SSH to/from)  however when I tried to spin up other images (Fedora, Centos, and Ubuntu/precise) from 
https://openstack.redhat.com/Image_resources  and the Ubuntu UEC page all of my VM's just hang with messages such as "waiting for hardware" or "booting...waiting".   And after about 5/10 minutes the status of my VM from horizon just turns to "shutdown".

Should I be able to use some of these images "as is" after putting them in the system via "GLANCE"?     I'm not sure if Virtual Box is impacting the boot of the instance or whether I have some other issue?   I've seen alot of different information about creating your own image, etc...however, all I need is a basic image for testing and just don't quite understand why I can't just pull in a downloaded qcow2 or img image that's already pre-built.

As I mentioned, I can create CIRROS without any issues but I'd like to be able to spinup a basic centos/fedora or ubuntu VM through openstack?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, sounds like your computer just doesn't have the RAM or resources to run any image larger than Cirros.

Answer (score 0):

How much memory and storage did you provision your CentOS 6.5 host vm with and how many CPUs? Many off the shelf images require 20+gb storage.

Also, check hardware virtualization is enabled https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt

One more thing to check if you are using a compatible flavor to launch these instances.

Try this, after you source your credentials:

## Check your HD space

```
df -h
```

## Download an image

```
wget http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img -O ~/precise.qcow2.img
```

## Import into Glance

```
glance image-create --name "precise-qcow2" --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --is-public True --file ~/precise.qcow2.img
```

## Check and copy your network id

```
neutron net-list
```

## Check your key name

```
nova keypair-list
```

## Boot your instance

```
nova boot --flavor 2 --image precise-qcow2 --nic net-id=<YOUR NETWORK ID> --key-name=<KEY NAME FROM THE DASHBOARD> precise-instance`
```

Hope this helps.